# How do I capture values (JavaScript Only) of each text box and display them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I am building a form using JavaScript and HTML only (business need - no server access).  I have a list of textboxes that I need the values from.  The user has the option of either filling out 1 textbox, or as many as they need up to 35.  I COULD create a function for each individual box

```
var a = $('#a').val();
var b = $('#b').val();
var c = $('#c').val();

if (a != '' && b != '' && c != '') {
    var abc = "this is a: " + a + "this is b: " + b + "and this is c:" + c;
}
```

and I could make a function for each scenario of each value:

```
if(a != '' && b != '' && c == '') {
     var ab = "this is a: " + a + " and b: " + b + "but not c";
}

if(a != '' && b == '' && c != '') {
     var ac = "this is a: " + a + " and c: " + c + "but not b";
}

if(a != '' && b == '' && c == '') {
     var a-only = "this is a: " + a + " but not b or c";
}

if(a == '' && b != '' && c != '') {
     var bc = "this is b: " + b + " and c: " + c + " but not a";
}
```

That's not even every scenario for just 3 variables, but I could potentially have up to 35 different variables that I need to make a function for each scenario which is a huge chunk of time and space and I think after about 10 of them, it will get too messy and hard to maintain later if I need let alone all 35.

I feel like there must be a far more efficient way of capturing the values and displaying them if they are not empty other than going through each possible scenario.

My textboxes are dynamically created by clicking an "Add More" button

JavaScript:

```
 var max_fields = 35;
 var x = 0;
 $('#add').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(x < max_fields){
    x++;
        var inps = $('#wrapper >div:last').data('count')+1 || 1;
        $('#wrapper').append('<div class="date-time-list" data-count="'+inps+'"><input type="text" name="date_count' + inps + '" id="date_count'+inps+'" class="inp"/><input type="text" name="time_count' + inps + '" id="time_count'+inps+'" class="inp"/><a class=remove>Remove</a><br><br></div>');
  }
 });    

 $('#wrapper').on('click' , 'a.remove' ,function(){
    var inps = $('#wrapper > div:last').data('count')-1 || 1;
    x--;
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

HTML:

```
 <tr class="list" style="line-height:1em;">
    <td>
        Please fill in the dates and times 
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong>Dates</strong> &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <strong>Times</strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="list" style="line-height:1em;">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="wrapper">                     
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="list">
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="add">Add More</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you post your an example of your textboxs? are the text boxes static or created dynamically?

Comment: They are created dynamically.  There's not enough room in the comment, so I added it to the original question

Comment: I adapted my answer to exactly match your use case. Should work out of the box now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this little snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/0h52y0Ly/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(){
        var content = '';
        var countOfTextareasFilled = 0;
        $('textarea').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val().length){
                content += $(this).val() + '\n\n';
                countOfTextareasFilled++;
            }
        });
        alert(countOfTextareasFilled + ' text boxes have been filled. Contents are:\n\n' +content);
    });
});
```

It shows a very generic approach to your task. You should be able to adapt it to your needs very easily.

**EDIT:**
I am fairly certain, that adapting a perfectly functioning generalized solution to your special use case, is something you should do yourself. But here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/cb7ujmsw/

```
$('#evaluate').click(function(){
        var content = '';
        var data = [];
        var dateField, timeField;
        $('.date-time-list').each(function(){
            dateField = $('#date_count' + $(this).data('count'));
            timeField = $('#time_count' + $(this).data('count'));
            if (dateField.val().length && timeField.val().length){
                data.push({
                    date: dateField.val(),
                    time: timeField.val()
                }); 
            }
        });
        alert(data.length + ' complete datetimes. Data:\n\n' +JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

I added a button with the ID "evaluate". The rest is completely your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a way to select all relevant inputs (*in this example all elements have the `check-me` class*)

```js
$(function(){
  $('.do-the-check').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var inputs = $('.check-me', this.form),
        empty = inputs.filter(function(){return this.value === ''}),
        nonempty = inputs.not(empty),
        message = 'This is ';
    
    if (nonempty.length){
      message += nonempty.map(function(){return this.name + ':' + this.value}).get().join(' and ');
    }
    if (empty.length){
      if (nonempty.length){
        message += ' but ';
      }
      message += 'not ' + empty.map(function(){return this.name;}).get().join(' or ');
    }
   
    alert(message);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  a:<input name="a" class="check-me"><br/>
  b:<input name="b" class="check-me"><br/>
  c:<input name="c" class="check-me"><br/>
  d:<input name="d" class="check-me"><br/>
  e:<input name="e" class="check-me"><br/>
  f:<input name="f" class="check-me"><br/>
  g:<input name="g" class="check-me"><br/>
  h:<input name="h" class="check-me"><br/>
  i:<input name="i" class="check-me"><br/>
  j:<input name="j" class="check-me"><br/>
  <button class="do-the-check">check them</button>
</form>
```